# How to escape back slashes '\' in a Java string while ignoring all the places where '\' is used for escaping standard characters?

Tags: java, string, unicode-string, unicode-escapes, stringescapeutils

I want to escape back slashes in a Java string. I tried to use the below code-

```
public static String escapeString(String str)
{
   return str.replace("\\", "\\\\");
}
```

This works like a charm. But, then I noticed that I also have some scenarios where the "\" character is used intentionally for escaping some standard characters like '\n', '\r', '\t' etc. Well, I don't want these '\' characters to get escaped because then these will become like '\n', '\r', '\t' which is not intended. Bellow example will make it clearer-

I/P String-

mdlhCw~pzOb@KV\Sd@c@CGK_DZiI|AuH\rdCiNrGi^xQ}HjDkFf@_IyTf@mKNm@H}C]

O/P String-

mdlhCw~pzOb@KV\Sd@c@CGK_DZiI|AuH\tdCiNrGi^xQ}HjDkFf@_IyTf@mKNm@H}C]

So, here I am escaping the '\' before 'S' but not the '\' before 't'.
Other than brute force by checking for every possible scenario, is there any other way to doe that ?

Comment: I think you need to escape only in specific cases and not always

Comment: `str.replace("\\", "\\\\").replace("\\\\n","\\n").replace("\\\\t","\\t) ...` What about that ?

Comment: Why? What is the reason you need to do this?

Comment: @EJP I need to send this big string to the server from my android app. Now while sending it, I was previously escaping all the '\' characters (otherwise, they couldn't be sent via http) Now, I have this issue because of which the decoded string doesn't work at all.

Comment: But, isn't "\\" always a backlash not escaping anything ? `\n`, `\r`, `\t` etc are characters, and not a '\\' followed by a letter. How is your String formed to have "\\r" that need to be interpreted as "\r" ?

Answer (score 0):

use the String.replaceAll method, which accepts a regular expression as an input to find strings to replace.

Place a regular expression that matches all backslashes, except those that have your blacklisted character next to it.